# struggle to understand tkinter multi classes

Tags: python, class, inheritance, tkinter

I am struggling to understand the concept and the coding specifically.  A few kind members have gave me some guidance, but their codes are above my understanding.  If someone can just correct this code for me then at least I will understand and overcome this part.  I do understand basic class accessing methods from another class without tkinter, but with tkinter, i am confused.

If I do everything in one class, then all the codes work.  this is shown with # to show I am trying on my own. I even making sure self.lower_tabs_dict is loaded properly by doing a print statement.  to advance the programing, I wanted to use more classes, and when I put in the "Class Week" it gives me an error

```
self.button = tk.Button(self.lower_tabs_dict["Week 1"], text="test 
            button", bg="salmon",)
AttributeError: 'Week' object has no attribute 'lower_tabs_dict'
```

... which tells me that I am not access that variable correctly.  How would I do that? thank you again.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Application(tk.Frame): #inherent from frame.
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="tan")
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack()

        self.lower_tabs = ["Week 1", "Week 2",]
        self.lower_tabs_dict = {}

        self.buttons_dict = {}
        self.GUI()

    def GUI(self): #the function that runs all the GUI functions.
        self.week1 = Week()
        self.create_lower_tabs()

    ####---------create grid_GUI---------------------####

    def create_lower_tabs(self):
        style1 = ttk.Style()
        style1.configure("down.TNotebook", tabposition = "sw")
        self.tabControl_lower = ttk.Notebook(self, width=1100,     
                  height=550, padding = 0, style = "down.TNotebook" )  
        for name in self.lower_tabs: 
            self.tab=tk.Frame(self.tabControl_lower, bg='old lace')   
            self.tabControl_lower.add(self.tab, text=name, )
            self.lower_tabs_dict[name] = self.tab
            self.tabControl_lower.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        #print (self.lower_tabs_dict["Week 1"])
        #print (self.lower_tabs_dict["Week 2"])

        #for name in self.lower_tabs:
        #self.button = tk.Button(self.lower_tabs_dict[name], text = 
                     #"Calculate") 
        #self.buttons_dict[name] = self.button
        #self.button.pack()

class Week(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(self.lower_tabs_dict["Week 1"], 
            text="test button", bg="salmon",)
        self.button.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(self.lower_tabs_dict["Week 2"], text =   
             "this page 2 button", bg = "salmon")
        self.button.pack()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("class basic window")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your error does explain the problem. Class `Week` does not have an attribute defined anywhere that says `lower_tabs_dict`. I think what you need to do is add `self.parent = parent` and then in your button you can do `self.parent.lower_tabs_dict["Week 1"]`. Also order of operation is an issue. You run class `Week` before creating tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues that stop your code from working here.

the 1st is the order you are calling `Week` in. You try to create the `Week` class before you have created your tabs.

2nd you need to pass self to `Week` from the Application class. This is needed so `Week` can access the class attributes of `Application`.

Here is you code cleaned up a bit and I redid your `create_lower_tabs` method as the way you were going about creating each tab was a bit unorthodox and unneeded.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="tan")
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack()
        self.lower_tabs = ["Week 1", "Week 2"]
        self.lower_tabs_dict = {}
        self.buttons_dict = {}
        self.create_lower_tabs()
        self.week1 = Week(self)
        self.week1.pack()

    def create_lower_tabs(self):
        style1 = ttk.Style()
        style1.configure("down.TNotebook", tabposition="sw")
        self.tab_control_lower = ttk.Notebook(self, width=1100, height=550, padding=0, style="down.TNotebook")
        for name in self.lower_tabs:
            self.lower_tabs_dict[name] = tk.Frame(self.tab_control_lower, bg='old lace')
            self.tab_control_lower.add(self.lower_tabs_dict[name], text=name)
        self.tab_control_lower.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)


class Week(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        tk.Button(self.parent.lower_tabs_dict["Week 1"], text="test button", bg="salmon",).pack()
        tk.Button(self.parent.lower_tabs_dict["Week 2"], text="this page 2 button", bg="salmon").pack()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("class basic window")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With that I really think you should inherit from `Tk()` instead of Frame for the `Application` class as its going to be your main window.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("class basic window")
        self.config(background="LightBlue4")
        self.lower_tabs = ["Week 1", "Week 2"]
        self.lower_tabs_dict = {}
        self.buttons_dict = {}
        self.create_lower_tabs()
        self.week1 = Week(self)
        self.week1.pack()

    def create_lower_tabs(self):
        style1 = ttk.Style()
        style1.configure("down.TNotebook", tabposition="sw")
        self.tab_control_lower = ttk.Notebook(self, width=1100, height=550, padding=0, style="down.TNotebook")
        for name in self.lower_tabs:
            self.lower_tabs_dict[name] = tk.Frame(self.tab_control_lower, bg='old lace')
            self.tab_control_lower.add(self.lower_tabs_dict[name], text=name)
        self.tab_control_lower.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)


class Week(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        tk.Button(self.parent.lower_tabs_dict["Week 1"], text="test button", bg="salmon",).pack()
        tk.Button(self.parent.lower_tabs_dict["Week 2"], text="this page 2 button", bg="salmon").pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you for all the clarifications.  @Mike - SMT the code works, and  I was reading super() all afternoon.  I just want to make sure that I understand your structure, the super() in  the base class is allowing class Week to "access" all the objects in  class (Application)?  thanks again for all the helps.

Comment: @fishtang `super()` allows Application to access all the methods of `Tk()` in this case. Essentially turning application into `Tk()` that you normally use for `root = Tk()`. This is part of inheriting from other methods. In this particular case `super()` is doing the same thing as say `tk.Frame.__init__(self)` would do for your `Frame class` but just for the `Tk` class here. `super().__init__()` is a catch all that you can use for any inheriting classes.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no differences between tkinter classes and any other type of python classes. In this case you're trying to use an element in a dictionary before you create that element. It doesn't matter if the dictionary contains widgets or anything else, you can't reference something before it exists.

Specifically, `self.lower_tabs_dict["Week 1"]` is created in `create_lower_tabs`. You reference it in `Week.__init__`, but you create an instance of `Week` before you call `create_lower_tabs`.